# If $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, is $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z\left[\frac{1+\sqrt d}{2}\right]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

If $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, is $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z\left[\frac{1+\sqrt d}{2}\right]$?

Is $\mathbb Q\left[\frac{1+\sqrt d}{2}\right]$?

I am confused about quadratic integers and quadratic integer rings and this is one question I have on my mind.

Comment: What is the difference between the two? (Hint: can you exhibit $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{d}=a\cdot\dfrac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}+b$?)

Comment: If $a=2$ and $b=-1$, then the equality holds. But how does this help?

Comment: The key is the difference between $\mathbb{Z}[\tau]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\tau]$; _all_ fractions are equivalent under the latter, so it makes no difference whether we speak of adding the element $\sqrt{d}$ or $(1+\sqrt{d})/2$ or even $\frac13(5+7\sqrt{d})$ - the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ by any of these will wind up being equivalent to the others. It's only when looking at the _integer_ ring that we need to be fussy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes thats true, observe that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb Z[\frac{\sqrt d+1}{2}]$, because every field containing $\mathbb Z[\frac{\sqrt d+1}{2}]$ must contain $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt d$.

Comment: When $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, why do we need to separate it from when $d \equiv 2, 3 \pmod 4$?

Comment: You don't need that...this statement holds for every integer $d$. The ring $\mathbb Z[\frac{\sqrt d+1}{2}]$ is used to show the ring of integers of the number field $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$,

Comment: Right, when $d \equiv 2$ or $\equiv 3 \pmod 4$, the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q [\sqrt d]$ is $\mathbb Z[\frac{\sqrt d+1}{2}]$. But why the need to separate it from $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$?

Comment: You don't need to seperate it...

Comment: $\mathbb Z[\omega]$, where $\omega = \sqrt d$ if $d \equiv 2, 3 \pmod 4$, or $\omega = (1+\sqrt d)/2$ if $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, is the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Right. So why the need to separate into those two cases?

Comment: These condition is only need to find the ring of integers of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$, not to find field of fractions of $\mathbb Z[\frac{\sqrt d+1}2]$! Understand?

Comment: I got it. But I was trying to understand ring of quadratic integers in general

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23643/discussion-between-k1-m-and-al-jebr).

Comment: You may find David Tall's book a good point to start...or more classic book written by Dedekind.